# php cUrl blocked on betfair?

Tags: php, curl, web-scraping, betfair

I'm trying to do web scraping on betfair.com site with this code php:

```
<?php    
    // Defining the basic cURL function
    function curl($url) {
        $ch = curl_init();  // Initialising cURL
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);    // Setting cURL's URL option with the $url variable passed into the function
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE); // Setting cURL's option to return the webpage data
        $data = curl_exec($ch); // Executing the cURL request and assigning the returned data to the $data variable
        curl_close($ch);    // Closing cURL
        return $data;   // Returning the data from the function
    }    

    $scraped_website = curl("https://www.betfair.com/exchange/football");       
    echo $scraped_website;          
?>
```

the code in this way works.

But if instead of "https://www.betfair.com/exchange/football" choose "https://www.betfair.com/exchange/football/event?id=28040884" 
the code stops working.

Help please.

Comment: what is the error you are getting?

Comment: I get a blank page when you launch the php code

Comment: Can you add these in your function and try  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE); curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);

Comment: Do you have permission to scrape their data? This is probably against their terms of service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

look at the headers curl receives:

```
 HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily
 Location: https://www.betfair.com/exchange/plus/#/football/event/28040884
 Cache-Control: no-cache
 Pragma: no-cache
 Date: Fri, 09 Dec 2016 17:38:52 GMT
 Age: 0
 Transfer-Encoding: chunked
 Connection: keep-alive
 Server: ATS/5.2.1
 Set-Cookie: vid=00956994-084c-444b-ad26-38b1119f4e38; Domain=.betfair.com; Expires=Mon, 01-Dec-2022 09:00:00 GMT; Path=/
 X-Opaque-UUID: 80506a77-12c1-4c89-b4a6-fa499fd23895
```

actually https://www.betfair.com/exchange/football/event?id=28040884 send a 302 Moved Temporarily HTTP redirect, and your script does not follow redirects, that's why it's not working. fix that (using CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION), and your code works fine. fixed code:

```
function curl($url) {
    $ch = curl_init();  // Initialising cURL
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);    // Setting cURL's URL option with the $url variable passed into the function
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE); // Setting cURL's option to return the webpage data
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
    $data = curl_exec($ch); // Executing the cURL request and assigning the returned data to the $data variable
    curl_close($ch);    // Closing cURL
    return $data;   // Returning the data from the function
}
var_dump(curl("https://www.betfair.com/exchange/football/event?id=28040884"));
```

(i would also recommend using CURLOPT_ENCODING=>'' , that will make curl use compressed transfer if supported, and HTML compresses really, really good using gzip which curl is usually compiled to support, which makes the site download much faster, which makes curl_exec() return much faster)

Comment: I tested your code on my website posted on x10hosting, but still does not work.
It could be the fault of the hosting site?

Comment: sigh. are you on IRC or facebook? send a message to hanshenrik at irc://irc.freenode.net/ or https://www.facebook.com/hanshenrik.bergan within the next 2 hours and i can probably help you figure it out